# Subtract vector from matrix based on data.frame efficiently

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix `X`, two data frames `A` and `B` and to vectors of indices `vec_a` and `vec_b`. `A` and `B` contain an index variable each, where the values correspond to the values in `vec_a` and `vec_b`. Other than that, `A` and `B` contain as as many values as there are columns in `X`:

```
# original data
X <- matrix(rnorm(200),100,2)

# values to substract in data.frames
A <- data.frame(index_a = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))
B <- data.frame(index_b = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))

# indices, which values to substract (one for each row of X)
vec_a <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)
vec_b <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)
```

What I want to achieve is the following: For each row `iii` in `X` get the values `value1` and `value2` from `A` and `B` based on elements `iii` in the vectors `vec_a` and `vec_b`. Then, subtract these values from the corresponding row in `X`. May sound a bit confusing, but I hope the following solution makes it more clear what the goal is:

```
# iterate over all rows of X 
for(iii in 1:nrow(X)){

  # get correct values
  X_clean <- A[which(A$index_a == vec_a[iii]),-1] -    # subtract correct A value
             B[which(B$index_b == vec_b[iii]),-1]      # subtract correct B value

  # this intermediate step is necessary, otherwise we substract a data.frame from a matrix
  X_clean <- as.numeric(X_clean)  

  # subtract from X
  X[iii,] = X[iii,] - X_clean

}
```

Note that we have to convert to `numeric` in my loop solution, otherwise `X` loses class `matrix` as we subtract a `data.frame` from a `matrix`. My solution works fine, until you need to do that for many matrices like `A` and `B` and for millions of observations. Is there a solution that does not rely on looping over all rows?

EDIT

Thanks, both answers improve the speed of the code massively. I chose the answer by StupidWolf as it was more efficient than using `data.table`:

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
   datatable   5557.355   5754.931   6052.402   5881.729   5975.386  14154.040   100  b 
 stupid.wolf    818.529   1172.840   1311.784   1187.593   1221.164   4777.743   100 a  
        loop 111748.790 115141.149 116677.528 116109.571 117085.048 156497.999   100   c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just match the rows:

```
set.seed(111)
# original data
X <- matrix(rnorm(200),100,2)

A <- data.frame(index_a = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))
B <- data.frame(index_b = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))

vec_a <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)
vec_b <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)

newX <- X - as.matrix(A[match(vec_a,A$index_a),-1]-B[match(vec_b,B$index_b),-1])
```

Then we run your loop:

```
for(iii in 1:nrow(X)){

  X_clean <- A[which(A$index_a == vec_a[iii]),-1] -    # subtract correct A value
             B[which(B$index_b == vec_b[iii]),-1]      # subtract correct B value

  X_clean <- as.numeric(X_clean)  
  X[iii,] = X[iii,] - X_clean
}
```

And check the values are equal:

```
all.equal(c(newX),c(X))
[1] TRUE
```

Match should be pretty fast, but if it is still too slow, you can just call out the values of `A` using `vec_a`, like `A[vec_a,]` ..

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses `data.table` for easy joining.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(111)
X <- matrix(rnorm(200),100,2)
A <- data.frame(index_a = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))
B <- data.frame(index_b = 1:4, value1 = rnorm(4), value2 = rnorm(4))
vec_a <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)
vec_b <- sample(1:4, nrow(X), replace = T)
setDT(A);setDT(B)
dtX <- as.data.table(cbind(1:nrow(X),X,vec_a,vec_b))

as.matrix(
  dtX[A, on = .(vec_a = index_a)][B,
      on = .(vec_b = index_b)][order(V1),
       .(V2 - (value1 - i.value1), V3 - (value2 - i.value2))]
  )
            V1      V2
  [1,]  0.22746  0.7069
  [2,]  1.84340 -0.1258
  [3,] -0.70038  1.2494
...
 [98,]  2.04666  0.6767
 [99,]  0.02451  1.0473
[100,] -2.72553 -0.6595
```

Hopefully this will be pretty fast for very large matrices.